# Rmongodb: mongo.authenicate error "BSON invalid"

Tags: r, mongodb

I was trying the R package "rmongodb", but I failed at the authentication step. I'm using rmongodb 1.8.0, R 3.2.0, MongoDB 3.0.3, Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca. I created a root user with the password "aaaa", and confirmed that I can authenticate it in the Mongo Shell:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3
connecting to: test
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.auth('root', 'aaaa')
1
> show users
{
    "_id" : "admin.root",
    "user" : "root",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I try to authenticate it in R using rmongodb, it prompted an error.

```
mongo <- mongo.create()  # no error
mongo.is.connected(mongo)   #=> TRUE
mongo.authenticate(mongo, "root", "aaaa", db = "admin")  #=> FALSE
mongo.get.err(mongo)  #=> 10
```

So I went to check that the error code "10" means "BSON invalid - Not valid for the specified operation," which doesn't make sense to me. So is there anything that I did wrong?